# IE version 10.0.9200 "forgets" CSS styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a 'tab toolbar' that has 3 tabs.  The user can click on a tab and our web page shows different data depending on which of the 3 tabs was clicked on.

To remind the user which of the 3 tabs they 'selected', I change it's CSS class on the fly when it is clicked on.

The 'selected' tab gets the following changes:  (1) yellowish background with gradient; (2) larger font;  (3) width and height of the selected tab are increased by about 6 pixels each.

It works fine in Firefox.    But in IE 10.0.9200, the change to the selected tab's CSS class fails in terms of the background color and gradient.  For example, when tab #3 is selected the **first** time, no problem -- the yellow gradient appears (as do the larger font and increased width and height).

But then IE seems to "forget" about part of the 'selected' CSS class if I click on a different tab then click back on tab #3 again.  The second (and third and fourth etc.) time I click to select tab #3, the font size increase and width and height increase show up but the colored background with gradient are missing.

If I do a 'reload' on the page in IE, BAM the colored background with gradient suddenly return.

Here is the 'selected' CSS class:

```
 .selectedTabClass{
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom,  
                  color-stop(0.05, #ffec64), color-stop(1, #ffab23) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffec64', 
               endColorstr='#ffab23');
background-color:#ffec64;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft:15px;
border-top-left-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright:15px;
border-top-right-radius:15px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
text-indent:0;
border:1px solid #ffaa22;
display:inline-block;
color:#333333;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:18px;
font-weight:bold;
font-style:normal;
height:65px;
width:186px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffee66;
 }
 .selectedTabClass:hover {
background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, 
              color-stop(0.05, #ffab23), color-stop(1, #ffec64) );
background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100% );
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffab23', 
              endColorstr='#ffec64');
background-color:#ffab23;

 }
 .selectedTabClass:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
 }
```

Here is the HTML:

```
  <label class="selectedTabClass" id="tab3"
         onclick="handleTabSelect(3, this)">this is Tab #3</label>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
  function handleTabSelect(whichTab, thisOne)
  {
      document.getElementById(whichTab).className = "selectedTabClass";
  }
```

Is there something I need to do so that IE behaves consistently like Firefox?

Comment: Is it possible to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi my friend there might b prob with class add and remove may be u should try like this fiddle will work..http://jsfiddle.net/6JryL/

Comment: @codebreaker Hi I'd like to try that, what is the equivalent in straight javascript to 'removeclass' (I don't know jquery)

Comment: hi are all the fields  are labels..

Comment: @codebreaker yes all three tabs are labels.  I tried setting the class to null first, then setting it to the proper selectedTabClass to see if I could mimic the jquery's removeClass() but it changed nothing.

Comment: can u post the fiddle u have tried if possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue, but the subtle cause of it?, I have not come to grips with, I fixed it but I'm not sure why it was 'broken' in the first place.

As stated above, the problem of some 'missing' CSS styles on our web site was only occurring when using IE 10.0.9200 when accessing our web site located at our hosting provider.

When accessing our website running locally on our development server in-house, IE 10.0.9200 did *not* have any problems whatsoever.  So we thought is was our hosting provider's web server settings (or something that was different from our in-house development web server) because the same IE browser version did not exhibit this problem on our local dev servers.

Our website changes the CSS "className" dynamically for a tabbed toolbar to indicate which tab is selected.  Each tab is a 'label' html element.

The tabs have 2 types of CSS changes:
(1) in our javascript, a line of code **document.getElementById('tab3').style.backgroundColor = "white"**
(2) right after that, in certain cases only, we changed the class name of the tab by way of:  **document.getElementById('tab1').className 
                           = "showThisTabIsSelectedCssClass";**

In Firefox and in IE 10.0.9200 **running on our development servers** -- the change of 'className' seemed to 'wipe out' (or reset) the style.backgroundColor change that we were doing, under certain conditions, just before changing the CSS 'className' for the tab elements.

And Firefox did the same thing (wiped out or reset the style.backgroundColor change when we reset the 'className') when accessing our website on the open web.

But for whatever reason, the same version of IE, 10.0.9200, was *not* discarding the **style.backgroundColor="white"**  change even when the className was changed.  The style.backgroundColor="white" changed the tab element's background to white, then we changed the 'className' under certain conditions, and the new CSS class imposed a blue backgroundColor to the tabs, but the white backgroundColor was still there after the className change.

I'm not sure why IE 10.0.9200 only exhibited this problem when viewing our website hosted online at our hosting provider and not while displaying our website on our local dev machines.

The fix required us to conditionally avoid the line of code **style.backgroundColor="white"** by pre-determining a bit earlier in the code that we would ultimately need to change the tab element's CSS className.

In other words, IE 10.0.9200 was **persisting a style.backgroundColor="white" setting** even after changing the 'className' for the element, despite the fact that the new CSS class imposed it's own backgroundColor.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the below code is the exact pure js code for the jquery code i have posted

```
function hasClass(ele,cls) {
  return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
}

function addClass(ele,cls) {
  if (!hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
}

function removeClass(ele,cls) {
  if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
      var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
      ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
  }
}
```

ele--> id and cls--> classname..should work revert if not..for example like

```
function handleTabSelect(whichTab, thisOne)
  {

         var ele = document.getElementById(whichTab);
    addClass(ele, "be-still");
    // or
    removeClass(ele, "be-still");
  }
```

Comment: another twist.  The same version of IE, when I access our website on our localhost web server, does *not* exhibit this symptom.  So I'm beginning to suspect some sort of odd 'caching' that our hosting provider's web server is doing.  I have to apologize to Microsoft as it is not an IE issue after all, unless IE could somehow behave differently when loading pages from a localhost web server that would be different when it loads pages from a true 'on the net' web server.

Comment: hi what kind of problem r u facing currently pls explain and have u suceeeded in the coding i have provided..

Comment: I began then noticed there may not be any coding problem at all.  Nor a problem with this version of IE in this particular case.  So I'm going to contact our hosting provider and urge them to address this; I don't want to code around a problem with their web server setup because there may be other issues that their server setup might cause for us; I'd rather fix the real problem right now.  Thanks and I will pick this up tomorrow (it's nearly midnight here now) after speaking to our hosting provider and letting them see this symptom firsthand.